# Checkout Maven project from SCM - no connectors

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a problem with checkout Maven project in Eclipse Indigo. I've installed m2e plugin, Subclipse, Git, but can't select appropriate SCM type ? How to solve this ?

[image: Checkout as Maven project from SCM]

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (under Ubuntu Natty), m2e 0.12.1, and sure enough, this stuff does not work. So, why not checkout SCM outside of Eclipse and simply import Maven projects?

Comment: I remember that in the previous version of the Eclipse (Helios), i've installed connectors (svn for example) after m2e plugin was installed and SCM types appeared then.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6981001/60462 which contains a suggested solution.

Comment: See this question ow [m2eclipse - No Connectors for SCM?][1] too. It has a better solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981001/m2eclipse-no-connectors-for-scm

Comment: See this question [m2eclipse - No Connectors for SCM?][1] . Its answer provide an better solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981001/m2eclipse-no-connectors-for-scm

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Affan was correct. The connectors are all still there in Indigo, just hidden a little.

1. Start Eclipse and open preferences.
2. Find the Maven group and expand it.
3. Select the "Discovery" item and click "Open Catalog".
4. A dialog will pop up with all the goodies. The connectors are at the bottom.

Answer (score 21):

I ran into this issue with Eclipse where when you would try to Import a project via:

"Check out Maven Projects from SCM" from the project expoler the "scm url" drop down box would be empty.

After googling around, you must have subclipse installed from the Eclipse Marketplace (which I did) AND "Maven SCM handler for Subclipse" from the "Help->Install new software" dialog box (which I did not).

How to get Maven SCM Handler for Subclipse:

Assumption: You have Subclipse installed.

1. Click Help->Install New Software
2. Click "Add..." to add a new software site.
3. Add this site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0  (Alternative URL: http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/latest/)
4. Select the Maven SCM handler for Subclipse
5. Install

You can now use the Project Explorer context menu of "Import -> Maven -> Check out Maven Projects from SCM" and actually have a SCM URL to choose from in the drop down box, namely "svn".

Tested with Eclipse Juno

Comment: I tried out the steps from Bill Pappin's answer but was getting errors. Your answer worked like a charm.. Thanks!

Comment: +1, good explanation helped me a lot. I am using subversive instead of subclipse, though, so this was the URL that helped me in step 3 above: http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-subversive/0.13.0/N/0.13.0.201302121311/

Comment: Thank you!  I liked this answer much better than the one above it.  As that ended up installing 2 SVN connectors (if you aren't careful in what you select)

Comment: I replaced link in (3) with [http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/latest/](http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/latest/) from [this comment](http://www.buluschek.com/?p=292#commentauthor-12721) (Eclipse complained about a version conflict but offered an alternative installation) and it is still the best solution I found.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like there is some incompatibility issue between Indigo and m2eclipse.  [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/openmrs.org/group/dev/browse_thread/thread/1ce771eb90f78765/28bc7adc7eff0b94?show_docid=28bc7adc7eff0b94&pli=1) gives more details including a possible solution.

Hope this helps.

**Edit 1**:  Uninstalled m2eclipse 0.12.x from Indigo and installed m2e from Eclipse's [m2e releases repository](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases). This version shows a link to *download m2e scm connectors* from Eclipse marketplace (when you try to check out a maven project from scm).  I could see connectors for cvs, git and subversive.

Comment: There is no incompatibility at this time.

Comment: Currently, subversion 1.8 connector for m2e is not supported by m2e team and its corresponding issue in github is marked as "WONTFIX". https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-subclipse/issues/3

Comment: Thanks the link to the Google discussion really helped us.

Answer (score 5):

For those using subclipse 1.8.x there is a patched version of the m2e connector.
Here is the update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/1.0

*(Thanks to RockyMM for posting the link to the WONTFIX issue, which contained the link to the patched version.)*

Answer (score 3):

Indigo comes with m2e pre-installed. To get the connectors just click on link where it says find more connectors in the m2e marketplace. From there i installed the m2e-subclipse connector. This is a different approach from previous versions of Eclipse where you had to install another plugin from market place called "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Extras)".

Comment: I'm not clear where this link is that I'm supposed to click to get the connectors. I can't find it anywhere.

I do think your right though because I seem to remember seeing it in the last version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There was an unofficial update of SVN connector. To install it go to http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1557 download attachment org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature-0.13.0-SNAPSHOT-site.zip and follow the steps:

> - Unzip the file to an empty folder somewhere, remember that folder
>     In Eclipse,
> - go to Help/Install New Software…
> - Click “Add…” to add a new site
> - In the window, click on “Local…” and choose the folder where you unzipped the 
>     site before. The result in the Location field should look like file:/C:/
>     theUnzipFolder/
> - Click OK, choose all available packages to install, and continue the 
>     installation as usual

Answer (score 0):

This is related answer by "technocrat" with new update site URLs.

This is working with Eclipse 2019-12:

The problem: "Check out Maven Projects from SCM" from the project explorer the "scm url" drop down box is be empty.

You must have subclipse installed from the Eclipse Marketplace AND "Maven SCM handler for Subclipse".

How to get Maven SCM Handler for Subclipse:

- Background: The original website of this project (http://subclipse.tigris.org/) redirects to https://github.com/subclipse. The subproject "m2e" is important.
- Here, you will find a link to an Eclipse update site: https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/m2e/1.0.x/. Add this to the eclipse update sites.
- Now you will see "Maven SCM handler for Subclipse". Install it.

You can now use the Project Explorer context menu of "Import -> Maven -> Check out Maven Projects from SCM" and actually have a SCM URL to choose from in the drop down box, namely "svn".