# m2eclipse - No Connectors for SCM?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I have installed m2eclipse plugin to a remote machine with no connection to the internet, I manually did the plugin installation by copying the contents from `features` and `plugins` directories.

Now When I am trying to **Checkout Maven project from SCM** (my local repo), it doesn't shows me any connectors!~!~

Although there is an option to **Find the SCM connectors in M2E Marketplace**, but my machine has no connection to the net. Is there any manual way to install the SCM Connectors for the above said plugin ??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the M2clipse SCM integrations plugin . Update site: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras. Choose the following components: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse, Maven SCM Integration

Comment: At least for me, the mentioned update site http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras doesn't work anymore. [An answer to another question, including the follow-up answer comments helped me install m2e(clipse) SCM plugins (git) on Eclipse Kepler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12021728/923560).

Answer (score 7):

[image]

The screenshot has a link "m2e marketplace" in the bottom right where you can install the subclipse connector. Before you do that simply use the main "Help->Eclipse Marketplace..." and from the popular tab install subclipse. Then after restarting go back to the screenshot above for checking out as maven from SVN and use the link "m2e marketplace" on the bottom right and install the subclipse connector.

You then have SVN and MavenSVN functionality.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/535487/), you need to install the connectors from the **extra** update-site at http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html.

Comment: The extras site no longer exist in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question in another post ;)

The connectors are all still there in Indigo, just hidden a little.

1. Start Eclipse and open preferences.
2. Find the Maven group and expand it.
3. Select the "Discovery" item and click "Open Catalog".
4. A dialog will pop up with all the goodies. The connectors are at the bottom.