# Eclipse Maven multi module checkout

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm trying to checkout a maven project from SVN through Eclipse.

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

I checked out the project as a normal Java project and then imported the project into the workspace as "Existing maven project". Maven Checkout with SCM is not working as I can't see the SCM url dropdown is not displaying at options.

The problem is that Eclipse is checking out the 3 child projects and the parent project into different project instead of checking them out all the child projects under the parent project.

Parent (this project does not seem to be mavinized. I don't see dependencies in the project)


 
-child1_folder

-child2_folder

-child3_folder

child1 (mavenized)

child2 (mavenized)

child3 (mavenized)

Is the above expected ?

I've installed subclipse but it's still now displaying options in SCM dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods you may try.

Method 1: fix the "scm" thing... you need to install a connector, see

1. [Checkout Maven project from SCM - no connectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729511/checkout-maven-project-from-scm-no-connectors)  or
2. [m2eclipse - No Connectors for SCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981001/m2eclipse-no-connectors-for-scm)

Method 2: Check out it using a command line svn client (or tortise svn) and import it in eclipse.