# Can't install Maven SCM Handler for EGit for Juno

Tags: eclipse, egit, m2e, eclipse-juno

I've updated my eclipse indigo to juno via the Help->Check for updates menu. 
I noticed I had updates for egit (2.x) and jgit (2.x) which clashed with my current installations (1.3.x) and so I removed all my egit plugins (eigt,jgit,egit-mylyn and Maven SCM Handler for EGit). I then tried to install the above egit plugins and was able to install egit and jgit but was unable to install Maven SCM Handler for EGit.
I tried updating grvia the m2e marketplace and got the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201110251725   (org.sonatype.m2e.egit.feature.feature.group 0.14.0.201110251725)
>   Software currently installed: Eclipse EGit 2.0.0.201206130900-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 2.0.0.201206130900-r)
>   Only one of the following can be installed at once:
>   Git Team Provider Core 2.0.0.201206130900-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 2.0.0.201206130900-r)
>   Git Team Provider Core (Incubation) 0.8.4 (org.eclipse.egit.core 0.8.4)
>   Git Team Provider Core 1.1.0.201109151100-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 1.1.0.201109151100-r)
>   Git Team Provider Core 1.3.0.201202151440-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 1.3.0.201202151440-r)
>   Git Team Provider Core (Incubation) 0.11.1 (org.eclipse.egit.core 0.11.1)
>   Git Team Provider Core (Incubation) 0.9.1 (org.eclipse.egit.core 0.9.1)
>   Git Team Provider Core 1.0.0.201106090707-r (org.eclipse.egit.core 1.0.0.201106090707-r)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Eclipse EGit 2.0.0.201206130900-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 2.0.0.201206130900-r)
>   To: org.eclipse.egit.core [2.0.0.201206130900-r]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201110251725 (org.sonatype.m2e.egit 0.14.0.201110251725)
>   To: bundle org.eclipse.egit.core [1.0.0,2.0.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201110251725   (org.sonatype.m2e.egit.feature.feature.group 0.14.0.201110251725)
>   To: org.sonatype.m2e.egit [0.14.0.201110251725]

I guessed from the error that the artifact which is in the marketplace is not yet up-to-date and so I tried to download the latest m2e-git from the [nexus repository](http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201207041402/) but I didn't really knew what to do with it.
I placed the contents in a subdirectory of the plugins folder and did not see it appear in the "what is installed" dialog so I'm assuming it didn't work.
Has anyone managed to get this to work?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, this has been an issue for other m2e connectors as well since Juno was released.  I've posted the steps that I used to [get around this issue here](http://machineversus.me/2012/08/18/if-youve-upgraded-to-eclipse-juno.html).

Here are the instructions:

1. Click **Help**
2. Click **Install New Software**
3. Uncheck the box labeled **Group items by category** *(this step is important or you won't see the connector in the table)*
4. Paste in this URL http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201305250025/
5. Finish the plugin install wizard and restart the workspace

Comment: There's been an update. Currently, the latest version of the connector is at http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201305250025/ and I needed to install that to get it to work. In future, look in http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/ (or perhaps http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/) for further updates.

Comment: Thanks. Got my kepler working. Link provided by Michael Scheper worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately, the links mentioned above are not working now.

Comment: I have the same problem with the eclipse-sublipse connector. Unfortunately this solution (with the eclipse-subclipse directory instead of subclipse-egit directory of course) didn't work. It still cannot find the connector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

This will work for Eclipse 4.3 (**Kepler**): http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201305250025/

Remember to uncheck the box labeled Group items by category

Comment: Eclipse tries to scare me off saying it will uninstall Egit (my: 3.1.0), but then it turns out it means downgrade (my: to 3.0.3).

Comment: That's interesting, because this URL works fine for me on Eclipse Kepler R, Kepler SR1, and even Luna M2 without that scary warning.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen It seems, the latest nightly only supports egit up to 3.0.x, I'm having the oposite problem, can't upgrade to egit 3.1 because of the m2e connector :(

Comment: @mglauche, yes, currently you have a choice: new egit xor new maven-scm-git. Hopefully this is only temporary.

Answer (score 2):

I took the code from git and created a build that works with keppler + m2eclipse 0.14 + egit 3.x.

Use this update URL: https://github.com/micw/m2eclipse-egit-builds/raw/master/0.14.0.201401300919/

Don't forget to uncheck "Group items by category" or you won't see the package in eclipse's software manager.

Update 2014-01-30: I built the latest git version which allows to be used with any EGit 3.x version. Please use the new update URL in this post. I verified that it works with latest EGit 3.2.x

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this did not work with Eclipse 3.8.  The jonathan.cone solution using the updated URL in the Michael Scheper comment did work.

Answer (score 0):

Install the handler from
http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201305250025/
It works for Kepler SR1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with the following configuration.

- Eclipse Luna SR1 Eclipse
- Egit Team Provider 3.7.0 (I had updated the
  plugin via eclipse marketplace)
- M2E egit 0.14 (Installed via eclipse
  marketplace).

Initially I was also getting the error while installing m2e-egit but once I updated the Egit eclipe plugin, installation of m2e-egit worked perfectly.Hope it helps.