# Maven m2e-egit install failure under Kepler

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

Today I installed Maven plugin (m2e) from eclipse markerplace. Now I want to checkout a project from github. The "Check out Maven Projects from SCM" dialog grays out the "SCM type" drop down list so I clicked on a link to install a connector for git.

I found the connecter "m2e-egit" in another dialog, so I checked it, click Finish. It fails with the following message:

```
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201207041402 (org.sonatype.m2e.egit.feature.feature.group 0.14.0.201207041402)
Missing requirement: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201207041402 (org.sonatype.m2e.egit 0.14.0.201207041402) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.egit.core [1.0.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Maven SCM Handler for EGit 0.14.0.201207041402 (org.sonatype.m2e.egit.feature.feature.group 0.14.0.201207041402)
To: org.sonatype.m2e.egit [0.14.0.201207041402]
```

It claims I do not have EGit installed, but I can confirm that I have installed Eclipse EGit version 3.1.0.20131021548-r from "About Eclipse Features" dialog.

Other information I can find out:

Eclipse ： Kelper Service Release 1 - build id 20130919-0819

Eclipse.org - m2e : 1.4.0.20130601-0317

How can I fix this and check out my maven project from github?

Comment: I believe the issue could be your current egit version is "too new". This line: "*Maven SCM Handler for egit .... requires version Egit **[1.0.0,3.0.0)** ..."* tells you 3.0 is an upper bound. As you wrote you have version **3.1**.

Comment: So I will have to wait for m2e-egit being updated to use this feature? or try to build a version without the upper bound of egit version?

Comment: I would try to update the plugins, probably they already support that version you simply have a bit older installation. There is a button for that in the Help menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version of m2e-egit in the Marketplace is outdated and won't work with the latest version of egit. This can be fixed by manually installing the most recent version, as described in the thread [Can't install Maven SCM Handler for EGit for Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707971/cant-install-maven-scm-handler-for-egit-for-juno).

1. Click Help
2. Click Install New Software
3. Visit http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/ and copy the URL to the most recent subdirectory.
4. Paste in this URL (currently http://repository.tesla.io:8081/nexus/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-egit/0.14.0/N/0.14.0.201401060023/) and type enter, or click 'Add...' to save it for future reference
5. Uncheck the box labeled Group items by category (this step is important or you won't see the connector in the table)
6. Finish the plugin install wizard and restart the workspace

Comment: I had same problem in the latest version - Mars 12/2015 , update the egit to the latest version solved the problem.