# m2eclipse extras install sts

Tags: spring, maven

I'm setting up a STS (2.6.1) development environment and our corporate WIKI says:

> Install the Maven SCM handler for subclipse (m2eclipse extras) from
>   the following STS/Eclipse update site:
>   http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras

However, this site no longer exists and Help | Install New Software doesn't know what to do with it.

I've searched the web for other instructions and/or alternative site.

I've found "The Central Repository" at search.maven.org, which has maven-scm-plug files to download.

But, STS doesn't know what to do that with that site (through Help | Iinstall New Software), and if I download the JAR manually, I don't know what to do with it to install it manually.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

The m2eclipse plugin has moved to eclipse foundation, you can find it [here](http://eclipse.org/m2e/), but [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_updatesite_and_gittags) you can find old releases if you need.

The new version of m2eclipse has a new feature called 'connectors', in order to get them, inside eclipse:

1. Preferences > Maven > Discovery
2. Open Catalog
3. Browse the catalog and choose the connectors you need.

See also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729511/checkout-maven-project-from-scm-no-connectors).

Comment: Thanks, but there's no "extras" repository there, and a search for "Maven SCM" produces nothing.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks, but STS 2.6.1 doesn't have 'Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery'.  I'm now trying to use STS 2.9.1 in the hope that the newer version isn't broken.  But hit this error: Missing requirement: Maven SCM handler for Subclipse 0.13.0.201303011221 (org.sonatype.m2e.subclipse.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201303011221) requires 'org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found