# Maven Svn Integeration

Tags: maven, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

which plugin is required to get checkout as a maven project in eclipse luna and how to download it.I don't know the exact plugin to be installed for this.I tried installing m2eclipse, but it is not getting installed.

Comment: Maven and SVN have completely different puropses and are independent from each other. Therefore you can checkout your Maven project like any other project. In Eclipse this can for example be done with the subclipse plugin.

Comment: For eclipse Luna, I cant see the option to "check out as a maven project" when i browse to SVN repo. I want to know which plugin luna supports so that i can get that option while browsing the repo

Comment: Honestly, I do not use an Eclipse SVN plugin. I checkout my SVN projects with TortoiseSVN (under Windows) and in Eclipse I import them via Package Explorer -> Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects.
With this approach you have a clear separation between SVN and Maven, which was my point. But perhaps that is not what you want.
Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729511/checkout-maven-project-from-scm-no-connectors

They solved your problem.