# How to connect Maven and Perforce in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, perforce, m2eclipse

I am new to maven but have used perforce for quite sometime.

Our project repository is on perforce. Basically there's multiple folders with their own pom files.

What I'm doing currently is, on the command line I create a perforce workspace and sync the latest depot version. Then in eclipse, I go and import a maven project and give the path to this folder that i synced on the command line. Now i don't mind doing that, but whenever I edit a file, I have to manually go to the command line for that file, find it and do a p4 edit on it which is very annoying.

Is there a way to have my project imported as Maven and it automatically sync with my Perforce depot within eclipse. I have already tried using the p4 plugin but it checks out the depot as it is and does not give a project level view and I can't do a maven build/maven install on it.

I have also tried to import maven project from scm, but looks like maven doesnt support perforce within eclipse?

Please help, i'm struggling a lot with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please suggest? I havent found a solution been struggling with this for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by installing Maven and Maven scm plugins.
You also need to have perforce and perforce connectors add in installed.

And then by importing the project.
[image: Import Maven Scm screenshot]

Check for more details here

[Checkout Maven project from SCM - no connectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729511/checkout-maven-project-from-scm-no-connectors)

https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/creating-sect-importing-projects.html

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Hi Saurav, Thank you for the response. 

I have tried this. I do see svn under the connector now and I type my url using the following notation - scm:perforce:[username@]host:[port:]path_to_repository found at - http://maven.apache.org/scm/perforce.html.

The problem is though, once i select next, it shows me an option to click finish (along with choosing the working directory etc) and then when I click finish, nothing happens.

Please suggest what to do next.

Thanks.